# How to refactor this SQL query?

Tags: sql, db2

I am writing the following query to IBM DB2 server:

```
SELECT 
    EMPNO, 
    YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - BIRTHDATE) AS AGE,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - BIRTHDATE) ASC) AS RANK

FROM 
    DANDY.EMPLOYEE;
```

It works, but looks ugly, as I am repeating expression:

```
YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - BIRTHDATE)
```

But writing as follows doesn't works:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY AGE ASC) AS RANK
```

How to make it better?

Comment: Just my opinion, but I don't think that's ugly by Sql standards... any alternative to duplicating the `YEAR` function will probably be bloated...

Comment: Thank you, I'll bear this in mind. Maybe I just exaggerate DRY principle. :)

Comment: DRY is often a bad idea in database querying, just so you understand.  DRY is far less imporatnat than performance in the dataworld (ONe reson why using views to call views is usuually a poor idea). Do not try to apply object-oriented principles to database work. All code shouldfirst get the right answer or protect data integrity and security, then it should be opptimized for performance, then and only then should maintainibility issues be considered.

Comment: @HLGEM Thank you! I won't use DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
EMPNO, 
AGE,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY AGE ASC) AS RANK
FROM (SELECT EMPNO,
             YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - BIRTHDATE) AS AGE
      FROM DANDY.EMPLOYEE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know standard `ORDER BY` clauses usually accept the column index, though not sure if it will work with `DENSE_RANK()` - maybe try:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY 2 ASC) AS RANK
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not working. It returns result table with all rows ranked as `1`.

Comment: No worries - it was definitely a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to get `AGE`, then use `AGE` again as needed.

```
WITH
   CTEAGE AS
      (SELECT 
          YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - BIRTHDATE) AS AGE,
      FROM 
          DANDY.EMPLOYEE
      )

   SELECT 
      EMPNO, 
      CTEAGE.AGE,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(CTEAGE.AGE ASC) AS RANK
   FROM 
      DANDY.EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get it to work. I am new to IBM DB2, but just copying this query produces a syntax error.